# What JSF data can I store in a client browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm interested can I store into client side for example large hashmap or a List? I need something like a temporary cache to store user session data.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you could use [HTML5 client side storage](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5%20client%20side%20storage) in JavaScript. So far now, no JSF components exists which could do the job transparently. You'd need to write all the necessary JS code yourself or grab [jQuery](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20html5%20client%20side%20storage).

All JSF as being a HTML code generator can do for you is to print Java objects in JSON format as a JavaScript variable assignment with help of a JSON library such as [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
<h:outputScript>var data = #{bean.dataAsJSON};</h:outputScript>
```

The `getDataAsJSON()` should just return an already converted JSON string.

Comment: Do you know in the future which JSF version will implement HTML5?

Comment: JSF 2.2 will per specification officially support HTML5, but there are as far as I see no plans for standard components related to client side storage. See also this interview with JSF lead: http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/01/jsf-update-2.x