# How to Html5 Local Storage with p:schedule

Tags: html, primefaces

I would like to know how to store events (p:schedule) to Html5 local storage?

I went through

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39051

[JSF / PrimeFaces compatibility with HTML5 Storage methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320379/jsf-primefaces-compatibility-with-html5-storage-methods)

[What JSF data can I store in a client browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744431/what-jsf-data-can-i-store-in-a-client-browser)

Then went through HTml5 Localstorage tutorials

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

But still I am confused from where should i start?

One of the event generated format is

```
{"events" : [{"id": "afe434ae-edf7-4265-8422-fe65eb7aec15","title": " Emma - 30 - Unassigned - 07 30 PM-09 30 PM","pet": {"serviceTypeTitle":"30 Min Pet Visit","statusStr":"Accepted","employee":"Unassigned","prefEmployeeModelList":[],"serviceTypeShortCode":"30","hasTrainee":"false","id":0,"serviceTypeId":5,"traineeIdList":[],"traineeList":[],"traineeModelList":[],"trainee":"None","employeeIdList":[],"employeeList":[],"serviceRuleId":1,"originalDate":1408320000,"startDate":1408359600,"endDate":1408361400,"locationId":2,"status":2,"cost":0.0,"billable":1,"payable":1,"modifiedBy":0,"modifiedTime":1408599848,"editedTime":"Aug 18, 2014 11:00:00 AM","ruleStatus":0,"petId":0,"pet":" Emma","serviceId":0,"eventDetails":" Emma - 30 - Unassigned - 07 30 PM-09 30 PM","currStatus":2,"startDateVar":"Aug 18, 2014 11:00:00 AM","endDateVar":"Aug 18, 2014 11:30:00 AM","billableBoolean":false,"payableBoolean":false,"selectedHr":0,"selectedTime":0,"amOrPm":0,"selectedHrED":0,"selectedTimeED":0,"amOrPmED":0,"commentObj":{"id":0,"serviceId":0,"userId":0,"shared":0,"createdTime":0,"modifiedTime":0},"preferredContactMode":"SMS(text)","timeSlotFrom":50400,"timeSlotTo":57600,"timeSlotFromVar":"07 30 PM","timeSlotToVar":"09 30 PM","locationAddress":"2914 N Har Street , Kochi , 666675, India","startDateForHover":"Mon, Aug 18 2014, 11:00 AM","addressUrlForHover":"https://maps.google.com/maps?q\u003d2914+N+Har+Street+,+Kochi+,+666675,+India","role":"Administrator","changeList":["employee","cost","locationName","serviceTypeTitle","startDateVar","endDateVar","statusStr","strBillable","strPayable","modifiedBy","modifiedTime"],"eventId":0,"employeeModelList":[],"allDay":false,"personId":0,"eventsInviteesPersonIdList":[],"eventCreatedById":0,"eventCreatedOnInt":0,"checkIfNotAttendee":false,"petList":[],"recurFrequency":"Single","addFlag":"no"},"start": "2014-08-18T11:00:00.000000Z","end": "2014-08-18T11:30:00.000000Z","allDay":false,"editable":true,"className":"accepted"}]}
```

If any one have implemented the same, can please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage only handles strings so first you need to convert your object to a string. You can use JSON for this:

```
localStorage.savedValue = JSON.stringify(myEvent);
```

Then when you want to convert it back to an object you use:

```
newEvent = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedValue);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bmeh3evL/

Comment: If I have multiple events how do i save it to localstorage.save ?

Comment: You would have to save them as an array of event objects or if you had a fixed number you could use localStorage.saved1, localStorage.saved2 etc. To add an event to an existing list that is stored you would need to jump through a bunch of JSON'ing, eg: `localStorage.savedValue=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.savedValue).push(newEvent));` For this to work the intial value of localStorage.savedValue would need to be "[]";